# Unable to install phonegap app in android (installer_r18-windows.exe)

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed android sdk from this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.(installer_r18-windows.... android app is working fine.but my phonegap app is not running.same phonegap app is working in installer_r12-windows.exe

Error Message

```
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.mobilyzer/com.app.mobilyzer.MobilyzerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.mobilyzer.MobilyzerActivity
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.mobilyzer.MobilyzerActivity
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-03 19:55:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(743):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed you Jar file in some random folder and then did "Add to build path". This will work in versions older than r17. But now you have to create a folder named `libs` in your project folder and then just add the phonegap jar file in it and automatically it will be added to class path. And you will not get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the activity in the Android Manifest? Make sure the launcher activity has the right name? Both possible solutions :D